# ActiveRecord fundamentally incompatible with composite keys?

Tags: activerecord, subsonic3

I have been attempting to use subsonic for a project on which I'm working.  All was going quite well until I encountered a link table with a composite primary key.  That is a key made up of the primary keys of the two tables it joins.  Subsonic failed to recognize both keys which was problematic.  I was going to adjust subsonic to support compound keys but I stopped and though "Maybe there is a reason for this".  Normally active record relies on a single primary key field for every record, even in link tables.  But is this necessary?  Should I just give up on active record for this project or continue with my modifications?

Comment: I've actually completed my changes to subsonic which were not as difficult as I had expected.  Seems to work okay at the moment but more testing is required.

Comment: Could we see the code you came up with? I ran into this problem as well and would be good to get round the issue!

Comment: It is on a branch at github, http://github.com/stimms/SubSonic-3.0 under the compositKeys branch.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby on Rails does not support composite primary keys in model object out of the box. However, there are plugins that accomplish that, for example [this](http://compositekeys.rubyforge.org/).

You can have composite primary key on a join table, but Rails will not create that primary key, you have to create it manually.
See [this guide.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association)